# How do I generate a static root key for appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm building a game on Google App Engine in Python 2.7 and I have a set of several thousand items that I want to be able to access consistently.  It seems like the best way to do this is to use a single parent Key for all of them, but is there a way to generate a static Key that my app will know the value of without doing a non-ancestor query?

Specifically, I need to be able to do a lookup of up to hundreds of these items in a single transaction by a name or keyword that I can be reasonably sure an empty lookup means the item doesn't exist, and not just that it didn't happen to be found on this lookup.

[Structuring Data for Strong Consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) has something close to what I want, but I don't see where guestbook_key() is defined in their example.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

If you can define a unique key for all of these items then what specific benefit will you get by putting them all under a single ancestor ?

Assuming your name/keyword will be unique for every entity, why not just construct the key with just than name/keyword.

If they are all of the same type then a single query can fetch all entities.  Which is no better/worse than an ancestor query.

If these 1000's of items are of different types then a ancestor may be of use if you need to perform kindless ancestor queries.

Look more closely at your access proposed access patterns, how often things will be updated etc... before you decide.

Answer (score 1):

Note: using a parent puts all children in the same entity group. Main limitation of the entity group is that is has an write limit of about 1 write/sec.

So the question is: do you need to access entities in the consistent way all at the same time? If yes, then you might consider putting this data into one entity. If not, then you do not need to put them in the same entity group.

Also, note the you can use [XG transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Cross_Group_Transactions), which work on up to 5 entity groups (entities) at a time.